# can CSS access the input element identified by a label's for attribute?

Tags: css, css-selectors

Suppose the `for` attribute of a `label` identifies an `input`.  I would like to style the `label` based on the `value` attribute of that `input`.  If they are adjacent this is easy: use an adjacent sibling selector.  But I would prefer to follow the `for` attribute of the `label`. Possible?

Comment: i would say No .. but it depend on your HTML, maybe we can find a *hack*

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36118012/3597276

Answer (score 1):

In short – no.

The only way I can imagine doing what you're describing is as you mentioned – by using an adjacent selector / sibling selector. You need to reverse the typical html order of `<label>` and `<input>` to allow the selector `input ~ label` to work.

```css
.field-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
  font-family: "Menlo", "Consolas", monospace;
}

input:focus ~ label {
  color: darksalmon;
}
```

```html
<div class="field-container">
  <input id="cool-input" name="cool-input" />
  <label for="cool-input">Cool Input</label>
<div>
```